# capture mouse with Xlib

Tags: c, xlib

I want to write a simple Xlib program changing the mouse behavior (to give an example, invert vertical movement). I have a problem with capturing the events.

I would like the code to

- capture changes in the controllers position (I move mouse upward, `MotionEvent`)
- calculate new cursor position (`new_x -= difference_x`)
- set new cursor position ( move pointer down, `XWarpPointer`, prevent event generation here)

The code below should capture a motion event every time the mouse is moved, but it generates the event only when the pointer moves from one window to another... How to capture all the movement events?

```
#include "X11/Xlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Display *display;
    Window root_window;
    XEvent event;

    display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    root_window = XRootWindow(display, 0);
    XSelectInput(display, root_window, PointerMotionMask );

    while(1) {
        XNextEvent( display, &event );
        switch( event.type ) {
            case MotionNotify:
                printf("x %d y %d\n", event.xmotion.x, event.xmotion.y );
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Related:

[X11: How do I REALLY grab the mouse pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792954/x11-how-do-i-really-grab-the-mouse-pointer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your program receives mouse events, it receives a copy of the events; copies are also sent to other programs that are listening for those events (see [`XSelectInput(3)`](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/XSelectInput.3.xhtml)).  You cannot override this without using [`XGrabPointer(3)`](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/XGrabPointer.3.xhtml) to take exclusive ownership of the mouse, which will prevent other programs from receiving *any* mouse events.  In short, you can't actually do what you are trying to do.

Note also that if a client has specified `PointerMotion` in its do-not-propagate mask for one of its windows, you will not receive any pointer motion events within its window (again, unless you do a grab).

Comment: Thanks. In the perfect case I would like to grab the mouse events "before" they are processed by the X input layer (but messing with mouse drivers would be too low probably). Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: X11 doesn't generally provide for this level of control; if you can't do it with the XInput API, you would indeed need to do it at the level of a driver or at least a server plugin.  X11 isn't very flexible in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the behavior of the mouse when it is being moved, I suggest you to play with the input properties instead of trying to do the processing in your program.

- `xinput --list`
- `xinput --list-props 'USB Optical Mouse'`
- `xinput --set-prop 'USB Optical Mouse' 'Evdev Axis Inversion' 1 0`
- `xinput --set-prop 'USB Optical Mouse' 'Evdev Axes Swap' 1`
- There's also the 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' property but for some reason it's not working for me right now.

You don't need to call the `xinput` program yourself: you can use Xlib calls (look at `xinput`'s source code).

Comment: Thanks. Inverting axes was only an example, I want to add something more fancy :)